# Couldn't determine repo type for URL: `https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`

Tags: react-native

I try to install pod for react-native project by using `bundle exec pod install`

I get the following error.

`[Hermes] Using the release tarball from Maven Central [!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL:` https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.